# Creating 2-bit/4 color bitmap in Java using IndexColorModel

Tags: java

I am trying to create a 2-bit/4 color bitmap in Java using IndexColorModel. However I seem to get an error when I run the code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.IndexColorModel;

public class bitmaptest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "اردو لکھیئے";

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);

        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        Font font = new Font("Arabic Typesetting", Font.PLAIN, 48);
        g2d.setFont(font);
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        int width = fm.stringWidth(text);
        int height = fm.getHeight();
        g2d.dispose();

        Color[] colors = {Color.red, Color.green, Color.yellow,  
                Color.black};  
        byte[] reds = new byte[4];  
        byte[] greens = new byte[4];  
        byte[] blues = new byte[4];  
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {  
             reds[i] = (byte) colors[i].getRed();  
             greens[i] = (byte) colors[i].getGreen();  
             blues[i] = (byte) colors[i].getBlue();  
        }  
        IndexColorModel cm = new IndexColorModel(2, 4, reds, greens, blues); 

        BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, cm);
        g2d = img2.createGraphics();
        g2d.setFont(font);
        fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.drawString(text, 0, fm.getAscent());
        g2d.dispose();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(img2, "BMP", new File("Text.bmp"));
            System.out.println(img2);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.write(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.bmp.BMPImageWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.doWrite(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
    at bitmaptest.main(bitmaptest.java:51)
```

I'd greatly appreciate any and all help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Either change the Size the IndexColorModel color component arrays to 2 or less

```
IndexColorModel cm = new IndexColorModel(4, 2, reds, greens, blues);
```

or change the Image type from the BufferedImage third parameter constructor call to:

```
new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED, cm);
```

The documentation gives these parameter descriptions which should give you a clearer view of what is going on:

> public IndexColorModel(int bits,
>                          int size,
>                          byte[] cmap,
>                          int start,
>                          boolean hasalpha)
>
> ```
> bits - the number of bits each pixel occupies
> size - the size of the color component arrays
> cmap - the array of color components
> start - the starting offset of the first color component
> hasalpha - indicates whether alpha values are contained in the cmap array
> ```